# Python: update dict string that has placeholders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, eval

Consider this string: `"{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10}"`. Now I want to update this "string" and add new key `d` with let say value `20`, so result would be `"{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10, 'd': 20}"`

Normally, you could just eval string (`eval` or `literal_eval`) into dict, update the way you want and convert it back to string. But in this case, there are placeholders, which would not be recognized when evaluating.

What would be best way to update it, so old values are kept the same, but "dict-string" is updated properly?

Comment: Any reason you are working on a string representation of a dictionary?

Comment: There are many XMLs files that have this so called context (XML files data are stored in database), which is string representation of dictionary. And such context can have placeholders which are evaluated at some point. And I need to update that context to add my custom keys. It would be easy, if not for placeholers, which at that time I don't know what their value would be nor I should really care.

Comment: What exactly are these *placeholders*?

Comment: For example `active_id`, is an ID of another record that triggered to open specific XML generated view. And that ID is dynamic, meaning it could be different depending from where (in a system) it was opened. So when context needs to be evaluated, it is then known what value to use, but Im doing update before its evaluated (its possible to write XML file to update other specific XML data, but there are many such files, so I figured it would be simpler to just find all I need and add my custom data (it is then done via python).

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show the problematic string where is impossible to use `eval`.

Comment: @MykolaZotko problematic string? Just try to eval the one in question:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This by no means a best solution but here is one approach:

```
import re

dict_str = "{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10}"

def update_dict(dict_str, **keyvals):
    """creates an updated dict_str

        Parameters:
            dict_str (str): current dict_str
            **keyvals: variable amounts of key-values

        Returns:
            str:updated string

    """
    new_entries = ", ".join(map(lambda keyval: f"'{keyval[0]}': {keyval[1]}", keyvals.items())) # create a string representation for each key-value and join by ','
    return dict_str.replace("}", f", {new_entries}{'}'}")   # update the dict_str by removing the last '}' and add the new entries
```

**output:**

```
updated = update_dict(dict_str,
    d = 20,
    e = 30
)
print(updated)
```

```
{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10, 'd': 20, 'e': 30}
```

```
some_dict = {
    'g': 2,
    'h': 3
}

updated = update_dict(dict_str,
    **some_dict
)
print(updated)
```

```
{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10, 'g': 2, 'h': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more robust solution that properly parses the dict, you can subclass `lib2to3.refactor.RefactoringTool` to refactor the code using a fixer that is a subclass of `lib2to3.fixer_base.BaseFix` with a pattern that looks for a `dictsetmaker` node, and a `transform` method that extends the `children` list with leaf nodes that consist of the tokens that will make for a new key-value pair in the dict:

```
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, refactor, pytree
from lib2to3.pgen2 import token

class AddKeyValue(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    PATTERN = "dictsetmaker"

    def transform(self, node, results):
        node.children.extend((
            pytree.Leaf(token.COMMA, ','),
            pytree.Leaf(token.STRING, "'d'", prefix=' '),
            pytree.Leaf(token.COLON, ':'),
            pytree.Leaf(token.NUMBER, 20, prefix=' ')
        ))
        return node

class Refactor(refactor.RefactoringTool):
    def __init__(self, fixers):
        self._fixers= [cls(None, None) for cls in fixers]
        super().__init__(None)

    def get_fixers(self):
        return self._fixers, []

s = "{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10}"
print(Refactor([AddKeyValue]).refactor_string(s + '\n', ''))
```

This outputs:

```
{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10, 'd': 20}
```

`lib2to3` is round-trip stable so all white spaces are preserved after the transformation, and a new node should be specified with a `prefix` if whitespaces are to be inserted before it.

You can find the definition of the Python grammar in [`Grammar.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/Grammar.txt) of the `lib2to3` module.

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/RudeLimegreenConcentrate

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can:

**Option 1 - Adding**

Insert the new string ", key: value" at the end of the string, before the "}".

**Option 2 - RagEx for adding/updating**

1 - use `find()` and search for the key. If it exist use the regex to substitute:

```
re.replace(regex_search,regex_replace,contents)
```

So using something like:

```
string = re.sub(r'key: (.+),', 'key: value', article)
```

2 - if the `find()` fail, use the add of the option 1

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about adding at the end of the string...

```
this_string = "{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10}"
this_add = "'d': 20"
this_string = f"{this_string[:-1]}, {this_add}{this_string[-1]}"
print(this_string)
```

will output

```
{'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': 10, 'd': 20}
```

If you need to insert the new string in between you can do something similar using string.find to locate the index and use that index number instead.

It's basically rewriting the entire string but strings are immutable what can we do.